# Occasional fault seen on xscal arm "Unhandled fault: imprecise external abort (0x416) at 0x40019004"

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

We have prodcution software running on the feild , which has ixp23xx netowrk processor with XSCALE arm core running linux 2.6.24. We have seen occasional problem from the feild and sometimes reproduced in the lab, the console prints the below fault line
"Unhandled fault: imprecise external abort (0x416) at 0x40019004".
Further digging, we found that we have few page table entries, where virtual addresses are not mapped to valid physical address. thus access to those virtual addresses can cause the impricise aborts. The final solution would be to remove the wrong mapping and thus next time we should get segmentation fault which would precise and easy to catch. But removing wrong entries will take some time and we have to create the build with debugging information thus this option is for later time.

Coming back to question,  As per the XSCALE data sheet, this fault can be made almost precise(+3 instr) with "stall untill complete" by setting the Xbit = 0, C bit= 0 and B bit=0. but i am not sure how exactly to do it in linux and is it going to help ? basically this looks like disable the DCACHE. The code under arc/arm/mm/proc-xscale.S is all assembly and i am not sure how exactly to disable. There is one option in the Kernel Config i.e. CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE , this seems to disable the DCACHE but will it be same as X=C=B bits equal to 0? below are the excerpt from data sheet

*

> Imprecise data aborts may create scenarios difficult for an abort
>   handler to recover. Both external data aborts and data cache parity
>   errors may result in corrupted targeted register data. Because these
>   faults are imprecise, it is possible corrupted data will have been
>   used before the Data Abort fault handler is invoked. Because of this,
>   software should treat imprecise data aborts as unrecoverable.Even
>   memory accesses marked as “stall until complete” (see Section 3.2.2.4)
>   can result in imprecise data aborts. For these types of accesses, the
>   fault is somewhat less imprecise than the general case: it is
>   guaranteed to be raised within three instructions of the instruction
>   that caused it. In other words, if a “stall until complete” LD or ST
>   instruction triggers an imprecise fault, then that fault will be seen
>   by the program within three instructions. If the MMU is disabled all
>   data accesses will be non-cacheable and non-bufferable. This is the
>   same behavior as when the MMU is enabled, and a data access uses a
>   descriptor with X, C, and B all set to 0. The X, C, and B bits
>   determine when the processor should place new data into the Data
>   Cache. The cache places data into the cache in lines (also called
>   blocks). Thus, the basis for making a decision about placing new data
>   into the cache is a called a “Line Allocation Policy”. If the Line
>   Allocation Policy is read-allocate, all load operations that miss the
>   cache

*

Answer (score 2):

The **StrongARM** and **XScale** are custom CPUs by Intel.  They seem to have some odd issues versus other ARM processors.

```
$ git checkout v2.6.24.7  # Activate time machine.
$ grep -B1 -A 9 CPU_XSC3 Kconfig 
# XScale Core Version 3
config CPU_XSC3
        bool
        depends on ARCH_IXP23XX || ARCH_IOP13XX || PXA3xx
        default y
        select CPU_32v5
        select CPU_ABRT_EV5T
        select CPU_CACHE_VIVT
        select CPU_CP15_MMU
        select CPU_TLB_V4WBI if MMU
        select IO_36
```

The relevant *Kconfig* is **CPU_ABRT_EV5T** and **CPU_TLB_V4WBI**, this selects *abort-ev5t.S* and *tlb-v4wbi.S* which gets the stuff that you are interested in.

## Function: v5t_early_abort

```
 * Purpose : obtain information about current aborted instruction.
 * Note: we read user space.  This means we might cause a data
 * abort here if the I-TLB and D-TLB aren't seeing the same
 * picture.  Unfortunately, this does happen.  We live with it.
```

I believe most CPUs don't have separate *I-TLB* and *D-TLB*.  The code is trying to emulate a *fault status* by reading and decoding the instructions that faulted.  The *I-TLB* (instruction MMU page cache) and the *D-TLB* (data MMU page cache) may not agree and the reading of the instruction memory may do something odd.

Are you the person *living with it*?  Ie, do you know if the **ixp23xx** XScale3 (XSC3) has separate I/D *translation look aside buffer* (TLBs)?

The other *oddity* is the **IO_36**.  The CPU has *36-bit* addresses.  See [domain.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/domain.h) for the source.  It appears that a **domain** becomes part of an *address*.  This maybe causing some weird effect but I couldn't find anything with a cursory look.

Sorry, I haven't answered your question.  This would be a long comment.

> Coming back to question, As per the XSCALE data sheet, this fault can be made almost precise(+3 instr) with "stall until complete" by setting the Xbit = 0, C bit= 0 and B bit=0. ... There is one option in the Kernel Config i.e. CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE

**CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE** will not fix your issue.  The `I-cache` and *write buffering* will still be active.  As well, your system will be extremely slow.  The kernel command line option `cachepolicy` can be used instead.  It supports, `uncached`, `buffered`, `writethrough`, `writeback`, and `writealloc`.  Some values might not be applicable to the platform.  I think `cachepolicy=uncached` might be equivalent to compiling with **CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE**.

Comment: [cachepolicy source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/mmu.c).  I don't see documentation on *cachepolicy* anywhere; expect craziness with some values.

Comment: Regarding the `v5t_early_abort`, odd things may happen with an i-cache hit and a d-cache miss as well; but the kernel comment doesn't mention that.  So even *unified-TLBs* may have issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. xscale XCS3 uses seperate I-TLB and D-TLB. regarding Data cache : thats not the solution, i thought of disabling DCACHE to find out the impricise fault instruction. I will try to look in the CPU_ABRT_EV5T and CPU_TLB_V4WBI code. BTW do you have any idea how to catch the impricise fault ? Other question is does VIVT cache can cause this kind of weird aborts? Just 2 days back we again saw the abort but this time it was "BAD Mode DATA abort" and to add the complexity PC was point at 0xffff029c, i guess this is the interrupt vector table ?

Comment: To complete above description, Pc was at 0xffff029c the flags showed   nzCv IRQs off FIQs on Mode ABT_32 ISA ARM segment user

Comment: The code is in *arch/arm/mm/fault.c*.  There are tables (struct array) with the string *BAD Mode DATA abort*, etc and function pointers to handlers.  The struct is `fsr_info`.  You can code your own routine and put it in `fn` and try to get more info.  I guess that it is due to separate I-TLB/D-TLB; I think this is rare. **0xffff029c** is some interrupt helper in *arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S*, near the bottom of the file (with high interrupt vectors).  You can even use `hook_fault_code` to update the handler in your machine file.  Good luck at slaying mighty bugs.